# Finding common string in array of strings (ruby)

Tags: ruby

Given I have an array of 3 strings:

```
["Extra tv in bedroom",
 "Extra tv in living room",
 "Extra tv outside the shop"]
```

How do I find the longest string all strings have in common?

Comment: do you mean 'any' substring, or should it only be compared from the beginning?

Comment: Also asked here: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_Common_Subsequence

Comment: @St.Woland: actually, it depends. For my particular example the result would be the same. But the reason for me to ask was actually because I wanted to know what I could do to locate a form for "common denominator" for any given array of strings.

Comment: @glenn: Longest Common Subsequence is different because it doesn't have to be contiguous.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a rubyish way of doing it. You should use a more advanced algorithm if you have a bunch of strings or they are very long, though:

```
def longest_common_substr(strings)
  shortest = strings.min_by &:length
  maxlen = shortest.length
  maxlen.downto(0) do |len|
    0.upto(maxlen - len) do |start|
      substr = shortest[start,len]
      return substr if strings.all?{|str| str.include? substr }
    end
  end
end

puts longest_common_substr(["Extra tv in bedroom",
                            "Extra tv in living room",
                            "Extra tv outside the shop"])
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to search for the beginning of all strings:

## Source

```
def substr( a )
    return "" unless (a.length > 0)
    result = 0
    (0 ... a.first.length).each do |k|
        all_matched = true
        character = a.first[k]
        a.each{ |str| all_matched &= (character == str[k]) }
        break unless all_matched
        result+=1
    end
    a.first.slice(0,result)
end
```

## Test

```
input = ["Extra tv in bedroom",
 "Extra tv in living room",
 "Extra tv outside the shop"]

puts substr( input ) + "."
```

## Output

```
Extra tv .
```

Answer (score 2):

[This wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) explains two algorithms that can be used to solve that problem.

Comment: And this wiki article gives a complete solution for TWO strings: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring#Ruby

Answer (score 1):

Also only for the beginning of strings.

```
def longest_subsequence array
  array.sort!
  first = array[0].split(//)
  last = array[-1].split(//)
  length = (first.size > last.size) ? last.size : first.size
  sequence = ""
  index = 0
  while (first[index] == last[index]) && (index < length)
    sequence << first[index]
    index += 1
  end
  sequence
end
```

But I think there ought to be a way to easily compare the beginning of just two strings for a matching substring - I just can't think of it right now!

Answer (score 0):

Don't think this scales particularly well.

```
def longest_substr(text)
    if (text.length == 0)
        return ""
    elseIf (text.length == 1)
        return text[0]
    end
    longest = text.inject(text[0].length) {|min, s| min < s.length ? min : s.length}
    (1 .. longest).to_a.reverse.each do |l|
        (0 .. text[0].length - l).each do |offset|
            str = text[0].slice(offset, l)
            matched = (1 .. text.length - 1).inject(true) {|matched, i| matched && text[i].index(str) != nil}
            if (matched)
                return str
            end
        end
    end

    return ""
end

puts longest_substr(["Alice's Extra tv in bedroom",
    "Bob's Extra tv in living room",
    "My Extra tv outside the shop"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if a response is still useful, but here's a solution inspired by @mckeed and @lins314159 code.

```
def longest_common_substr(strings)
    longest_substring = strings.map{|s| s.split}.max_by &:length
    longest_substring.inject do |target_str, token|
        r = Regexp.new("^#{target_str.nil? ? token : "#{target_str} #{token}".strip}")
        target_str = "#{target_str} #{token}".strip if strings.all? {|string| string =~ r}
        target_str
    end
end

puts longest_common_substr(["Extra tv and mat in bedroom",
                            "Extra tv and chair with view in living room",
                            "Extra tv and carpet outside the shop"])
```

Answer (score 0):

A better worded one:

```rb
  def longest_common_substring(strings)
    shortest = strings.min_by(&:size)
    max = shortest.size
    max.downto(0) do |size|
      0.upto(max - size) do |start|
        substring = shortest[start, size]
        return substring if strings.all? { |string| string.include? substring }
      end
    end
  end
```