# Convert range to pattern

Tags: ruby, pattern-matching, range

I have several ranges of numbers and I wonder if there are any algorithms to convert these ranges to patterns, like this:

```
Range:    5710000-5716999
Patterns: 5710*, 5711*, 5712*, 5713*, 5714*, 5715*, 5716*

Range:    5003070-5003089
Patterns: 500307*, 500308*

Range:    7238908-7238909
Patterns: 7238908*, 7238909*
```

I'm using Ruby, if it matters.

**UPDATE 1:**

More examples:

```
Range:    1668659-1668671
Patterns: 1668659*, 166866*, 1668670*, 1668671*

Range:    9505334305-9505334472
Patterns: 9505334305*, 9505334306*, 9505334307*, 9505334308*, 9505334309*, 950533431*, 950533432*, ..., 950533446*, 9505334470*, 9505334471*, 9505334472*
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Where are you using this pattern?

Comment: I need to use these patterns in some 3rd party software. It's a closed enterprise software, which accepts only this kind of data.

Comment: You're trying to solve the [longest common substring problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem), although your problem is constrained to substrings that are at the start of each string. Here's a good place to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158313/finding-common-string-in-array-of-strings-ruby

Comment: Okay, thanks for help.

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful, but next time consider waiting longer before accepting a solution. There may be others still working on answers and, in general, an early acceptance may discourage other, possibly better,  possibly just interesting, solutions. (Also, it is not unusual for an accepted answer to be shown to be incorrect.) Many here wait at least a couple of hours before accepting an answer. The point is, there's no rush. I know many who are new to SO haven't thought about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, I figured out how to make such converting using `group_by` method on the full range. I suppose, this algorithm kinda slow and inefficient, but it's very straightforward and works fine, so I'll stick to it.

```
def range_to_pattern(range)
  values = range.to_a
  while values.group_by{ |x| x.to_s[0...-1] }.any? { |_, v| v.size == 10 }
    patterns = []
    values.group_by{ |x| x.to_s[0...-1] }.each_pair{ |k, v| v.size == 10 ? patterns << k.to_i : patterns += v }
    values = patterns
  end
  values
end
```

Results:

```
irb(main):072:0> range_to_pattern(5710000..5716999)
=> [5710, 5711, 5712, 5713, 5714, 5715, 5716]

irb(main):073:0> range_to_pattern(5003070..5003089)
=> [500307, 500308]

irb(main):074:0> range_to_pattern(7238908..7238909)
=> [7238908, 7238909]

irb(main):075:0> range_to_pattern(1668659..1668671)
=> [1668659, 166866, 1668670, 1668671]

irb(main):076:0> range_to_pattern(9505334305..9505334472)
=> [9505334305, 9505334306, 9505334307, 9505334308, 9505334309, 950533431, 950533432, 950533433, 950533434, 950533435, 950533436, 950533437, 950533438, 950533439, 950533440, 950533441, 950533442, 950533443, 950533444, 950533445, 950533446, 9505334470, 9505334471, 9505334472]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def doit(range)    
  b, e = range.begin.to_s, range.end.to_s
  idx = b.chars.zip(e.chars).index { |a,b| a!=b }
  return "#{b}*" if idx.nil?
  (b[idx]..e[idx]).map { |c| b[0,idx] + c + '*' }
end

doit(5710000..5716999)
  #=> ["5710*", "5711*", "5712*", "5713*", "5714*", "5715*", "5716*"] 

doit(5003070..5003089)
  #=> ["500307*", "500308*"] 

doit(7238908..7238909)
  #=> ["7238908*", "7238909*"]

doit(123..123)
  #=> "123*"
```

The steps are as follows.

```
range = 5003070..5003089

b, e = range.begin.to_s, range.end.to_s
  #=> ["5003070", "5003089"] 
b #=> "5003070" 
e #=> "5003089" 
ab = b.chars
  #=> ["5", "0", "0", "3", "0", "7", "0"] 
ae = e.chars
  #=> ["5", "0", "0", "3", "0", "8", "9"] 
c = ab.zip(ae)
  #=> [["5", "5"], ["0", "0"], ["0", "0"], ["3", "3"],
  #    ["0", "0"], ["7", "8"], ["0", "9"]] 
idx = c.index { |a,b| a!=b }
  #=> 5
return "#{b}*" if idx.nil?
  #=> return "5003070*" if 5.nil?
r = b[idx]..e[idx]
  #=> "7".."8" 
r.map { |c| b[0,idx] + c + '*' }
  #=> ["500307*", "500308*"]
```

Comment: It seems, I found a problem:

`9044668619..9044668671
["904466861*", "904466862*", "904466863*", "904466864*", "904466865*", "904466866*", "904466867*"]`

Trying to figure out, how to overcome this.

Comment: @Alexey918331, why is that not correct? What should be the return value?

Comment: Also, I think it needs `return "#{b}*" if b == e`

Comment: In that case return must be: `["9044668619*", "904466862*", "904466863*", "904466864*", "904466865*", "904466866*", "9044668670*", "9044668671*"]`

Comment: Unfortunately, the rule that produces that result (which I've deciphered) cannot be deduced from the three examples you gave. I'll have a look at that in the morning. In the meantime, try to modify my code to obtain the result you want (but please don't edit my answer :-)). It would be a good exercise. Note I dealt with the `b==e` case. Thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: When you edit your question and the edit conflicts with one or more answers already given (here by adding more examples), you should indicate it's an edit. If you do not do so readers may conclude that an answer is incorrect--possibly even downvote it--not realizing that it was was correct for the initial question.