# How to summarize strings into shell globs

Tags: ruby, text

Are there any Ruby idioms or popular libraries for consolidating strings into a shell glob that would generate them? For example, given the strings,

```
abc1
abc2
abc3
```

I want to produce the string `abc{1..3}` or `abc{1,2,3}`. It's much like summarizing subnets in IP addressing.

I imagine a Rubyesque approach might involve sorting the strings and then building an array of their constituent characters, placing characters that don't overlap into nested arrays, recursively. However if there is something already out there, I'd rather not reinvent that wheel.

Comment: This smells like an X/Y problem. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve with this approach?

Comment: What is the X/Y problem I asked https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: sorry to disappoint, but no subterfuge here -- this is indeed what i'm trying to do! i'm writing some ERB templates to standardize issue verbiage, and want to summarize groups of related items (such as members of a cluster) for the benefit of readability by humans. i'm not trying to pipe out to a shell or something like that. the verbiage is intended for a technical audience, and `role01{a..c}` would be the friendliest way for us to refer to servers A through C in the first `role` cluster.

Comment: hello, looks like you need to find longest common substring http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158313/finding-common-string-in-array-of-strings-ruby and combine remaining chunks afterwards

Answer (score 0):

I borrowed the accepted solution to [Finding common string in array of strings (ruby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158313/finding-common-string-in-array-of-strings-ruby) and used a recursive algorithm:

```
def longest_common_substr(strings)
  shortest = strings.min_by &:length
  maxlen = shortest.length
  maxlen.downto(0) do |len|
    0.upto(maxlen - len) do |start|
      substr = shortest[start,len]
      return substr if strings.all?{|str| str.include? substr }
    end
  end
end

def create_glob(files)
  return '' if files.compact.empty?

  stub=longest_common_substr(files)
  if stub.length == 0
    expansion = files.uniq.join(',')
    return '' if expansion == '' 
    return '{' + expansion + '}'
  end

  pre =  []
  post = []

  files.each do |file|
    i = file.index(stub)

    pre  << file[0, i] 
    post << file[i+stub.length..-1]
  end
  return create_glob(pre) + stub + create_glob(post)
end
```

That works well for your example:

```
puts create_glob(['abc1',
                  'abc2',
                  'abc3'
                 ])
#=> abc{1,2,3}
```

It also covers more complicated cases such as variable prefixes:

```
puts create_glob(['first.abc1',
                  'second.abc2',
                  'third.abc3'
                 ])
#=> {first,second,third}.abc{1,2,3}
```

And even missing values:

```
puts create_glob(['.abc1',
                  'abc',
                  'abc3'
                 ])
#=> {.,}abc{1,,3}
```

Notice [brace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Brace_expansion) might produce strings that are not files. For instance, the last example expands like this:

```
$ echo {.,}abc{1,,3}
.abc1 .abc .abc3 abc1 abc abc3
```

So you have to be just a little bit careful using the output.